# Where clause in Linq and compare strings

Tags: c#, linq

```
public static List<table1> CRBTsongformis(string sSname)
{
    List<table1> crbtlist = new List<table1>();

    using (crbt_onwebEntities dbContext = new crbt_onwebEntities())
    {
        crbtlist = (from z in dbContext.table1 
                    where z.CONTENT_NAME.Contains(sSname) && 
                    z.STATUS!=null select z).ToList();
    }

    return crbtlist;
}
```

In my table1, column name CONTENT_NAME contain 'Jiya' and 'Jiya Re' values. I want to fetch only 'Jiya' when sSname argument contain 'Jiya' and only 'Jiya Re' when sSname contain 'Jiya Re'

Comment: .Contains is a method then how can I used this in that way ?

Comment: contains is like SQL "LIKE", where any word contains a matching string is found. you are looking for a exact match (==).

Comment: I have used it but its in this case no records found is showing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use == not contain:

```
where z.CONTENT_NAME == sSname
```

Comment: I have used it but its in this case no records found is showing

Comment: .Contains is a method then how can I used this in that way ?

Comment: See my update. You cant use contain in this case. please read more about contain method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try following code

```
public static List<table1> CRBTsongformis(string sSname)
    {
        List<table1> crbtlist = new List<table1>();
        using (crbt_onwebEntities dbContext = new crbt_onwebEntities())
        {
            crbtlist = (from z in dbContext.table1 where z.CONTENT_NAME == sSname 
            && z.STATUS!=null select z).ToList();
        }
        return crbtlist;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is more a Linq Question than MVC 3

```
public static List<table1> CRBTsongformis(string sSname)
{
    List<table1> crbtlist = new List<table1>();

    using (crbt_onwebEntities dbContext = new crbt_onwebEntities())
    {
        crbtlist = (from z in dbContext.table1 
                    where z.CONTENT_NAME==sSname && 
                    z.STATUS!=null select z).ToList();
    }

    return crbtlist;
}
```

It will be more accurate

Comment: Thank you @Lanorkin. Next Time I will make sure before posting!

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as follows.

```
public static List<table1> CRBTsongformis(string sSname)
{
    List<table1> crbtlist = new List<table1>();

    using (crbt_onwebEntities dbContext = new crbt_onwebEntities())
    {
        crbtlist = (from z in dbContext.table1
                    where z.CONTENT_NAME.Contains(sSname) &&
                     !dbContext.table1.Any(e => e.CONTENT_NAME.Contains(sSname) && e.CONTENT_NAME.Length > sSname.Length) &&
                    z.STATUS != null
                    select z).ToList();
    }

    return crbtlist;
}
```